# problem converting time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a post and i need to display how long ago it was posted.

When i do this

```
 <%= time_ago_in_words(Time.now - post.created_at) %>
```

i get the following error

> undefined method `abs' for 2011-04-17
>   17:16:11 +0300:Time

I think the app can't convert the time correctly . How can i repair this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got wrong syntax

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
```